# Computing the Analytic Center of a Polytope in Python

Tags: scipy, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I have a polytope described by a set of inequalities and equalities that are given as numpy arrays. These arrays will usually be quite large, as they describe the LP-relaxation of an MIPLIB problem. I want to compute the analytic center of this polytope. If possible, I'd like to do this directly from my Python code. However, I am also open to solutions that (for instance) write the polytope description to an MPS file and use another tool to compute the analytic center.

So far, I have tried implementing a primal-dual newton algorithm as described in "Interior-Point Algorithm: Theory and Analysis" by Yinyu Ye. However, this method is much too slow.
Another approach I tried was using a path-following interior-point method with a vanishing objective. To this end, I used [linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-interior-point.html#optimize-linprog-interior-point) from scipy. However, evaluation on simple examples shows that `method="interior-point"` gives an interior point that is different from the analytic center, even when I set `options={"resolve": False, "rr": False, "autoscale": False}` to prevent modifications to the polytope description. Using `method="highs-ipm"` will give a vertex solution.

I'd be happy to hear about any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

If you polytope is described as { x | a_i^T x <= b_i } then finding the analytic center amounts to minimizing function f(x) = - sum_i log(b_i - a_i^T x).

Function f is convex and self-concordant. I would recommend applying damped Newton steps, which should converge in a few iterations. The main computational effort will be solving the Newton linear system.

For a description of Newton's method with damped steps see section 9.5.2 in [https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) (*Convex Optimization*, Boyd and Vandenberghe) or https://francisbach.com/self-concordant-analysis-newton/ or